# python: how do I do locateCenterOnScreen with pydirectinput instead of pyautogui:

Tags: python, pyautogui, mouseclick-event

```
import time
import keyboard
import pyautogui
import win32api
import win32con

time.sleep(3)


def click():
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0)
    time.sleep(0.1)


while not keyboard.is_pressed('q'):
    start = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('img.png', region=(0, 0, 1920, 1080), grayscale=True,    confidence=0.50)
    if start is not None:
    pyautogui.moveTo(start)
    click()
```

I tried to put pydirectinput instead of pyautogui but locateCenterOnScreen dosent work with pydirectinput.